# Balance is always 0 in created account via web3js

Tags: web3js

I have the following code snippet which is supposed to create an account, make a transaction to that account, and get the balance then. I'm using **Ganache** as the provider.

However, no matter how many times I execute the code, the balance of the created account is always 0, whereas the balance of the Ganache account gets reduced every time. What could be wrong here?

```
const express = require("express");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3provider = "http://localhost:7545"; //Ganache
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(web3provider));
const app = express();

//generate private key
const privateKey = web3.eth.accounts.create().privateKey;

// create account
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);
console.log(account.address); //logs the address of the created account

// make a transaction
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: "0x7693e8197c20a665be2e1f20685dA7e65B91feE4", //Ganache address
  to: account.address,
  value: 10000000000000000,
});

// get balance
web3.eth.getBalance(account.address).then((result) => {
  console.log(result); 
  /*
  this always logs 0, but if I substitute with the Ganache address, 
  it logs the balance properly
  */
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for `sendTransaction` to complete, just like you do with `getBalance`.

For example:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: "...",
    to: account.address,
    value: 10000000000000000,
}).then((receipt) => {
    web3.eth.getBalance(account.address).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

BTW, there are several different ways to do this.

You may want to check out [this coding example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#id64).